# Listview not showing correct information when submitting comments

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I've created a real time database on firebase, I have it where on a post you can click into it and create a comment and those two are linked on firebase. But when I create a comment in the post, the information I created myself is changed to random letters and numbers and it saves like that as well instead of what I typed in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    package connect2you.com;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CommentingWindows extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textViewListName;
    EditText editCommentName;
    SeekBar seekBarRating;

    Button buttonAddComment;

    ListView listViewComments;

    DatabaseReference databaseComments;

    List<CommentsWindows> windowsComments;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_commenting_windows);

        textViewListName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewListName);
        editCommentName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCommentName);
        seekBarRating = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarRating);

        buttonAddComment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddComment);

        listViewComments = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewComments);

        Intent intent = getIntent();


        windowsComments = new ArrayList<>();

        String name = intent.getStringExtra(WindowsPost.LIST_NAME);
        String desc = intent.getStringExtra(WindowsPost.LIST_DESC);

        textViewListName.setText(name);

        databaseComments = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("comments").child(name);

        buttonAddComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                saveComment();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseComments.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                windowsComments.clear();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void saveComment(){

        int id = textViewListName.getId();
        String commentName = editCommentName.getText().toString().trim();
        int rating = seekBarRating.getProgress();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(commentName)){
            String name = databaseComments.push().getKey();

            CommentsWindows list = new CommentsWindows(id,name,rating);

            assert name != null;
            databaseComments.child(name).setValue(list);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Comment saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Comment shouldn't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

[I've uploaded a screenshot of the strange numbers and letters I get instead of the information I'm putting in myself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2vAi.jpg)

[This is the image of my real time database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P10gQ.png)

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

you are getting the Id of the element and not the element it self,
check if you put an empty constructor in your Comment.class, the correct name of the getters, and the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

U have added a value event listener , u should try child event listener rather than value event listener. So inside onstart use databaseComments.childeventlistener.........

Comment: I've added that in, no errors thankfully. I want the comments to show on the comment which it doesn't after changing to childeventlistener. Also the name's being saved to the database are strange and not what I typed in.

Comment: Can u please tell me your current code and a screenshot of firebase realtime database ?

Comment: I've attached the picture of my real time database and I've updated the code above to what I have now.

Comment: let me know pls

Comment: Inside on child added: 
 CommentsWindows    windowsComments   = snapshot.getValue(CommentsWindows.class);

Comment: This fixed an error but it still doesn't display the information from the database.

Comment: Inside on child added try to show the data inside a list view or textview on screen by getting your data from the object windowscomments.getComment(); something like that